# PHP - News Magazine Online

Tags: php, html, sql

This is my website:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S55uW.jpg)

As you can see I can't simply use a PHP Array that writes each news after each other.

Currently I use this method.

> BEFORE HTML

```
<?php
include 'config/db.php';

// Get Article 1
$g1_query = "SELECT * FROM articles where id = 1";
$g1_result = pg_query($con, $g1_query) or die("Cannot execute query: $g1_query\n");

// Get Article 2
$g2_query = "SELECT * FROM articles where id = 2";
$g2_result = pg_query($con, $g2_query) or die("Cannot execute query: $g2_query\n");

// Get Article 3
$g3_query = "SELECT * FROM articles where id = 3";
$g3_result = pg_query($con, $g3_query) or die("Cannot execute query: $g3_query\n");

// Get Article 4
$g4_query = "SELECT * FROM articles where id = 4";
$g4_result = pg_query($con, $g4_query) or die("Cannot execute query: $g4_query\n");

pg_close($con);
?>
```

> AFTER HTML

```
<div class="medium-8 columns">
<?php $row = pg_fetch_assoc($g1_result); ?>
    <div class="blog-post">
        <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $row['body']; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="medium-8 columns">
    <?php $row = pg_fetch_assoc($g2_result); ?>
        <div class="blog-post">
            <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $row['body']; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It works but as you can see, it has a lot of unnecessary code.
I would like too use another method instead.

Edit: 
A friend told me about this method, but I'm not sure how to use it:

```
<?php 

    $a_query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id";
    $a_result = pg_query($con, $a_query) or die("Cannot execute query: $a_query\n");

    while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($a1_result)) { 

        if($row['size']==1) { // If its a big value (Value 1) the news articles gets the div class blog-post
        echo '<div class="blog-post">
                <h3>'.$row['title'].'</h3>
                <p>'.$row['body'].'</p>
            </div>
        ';
        }
        elseif($row['size']==2) { // If its a small value (Value 2) the news articles gets the div class blog-post-smaller
        echo '<div class="blog-post-smaller">
                <h3>'.$row['title'].'</h3>
                <p>'.$row['body'].'</p>
            </div>
        ';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Switch to prepared statements.  This is totally totally insecure

Comment: its okey if its insecure. as long as it works.

Comment: @Akin: I can't see where there would be an opportunity for a hack - is there reading of user input I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code your friend gave you basically solves your problem:

```
    $a_query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id";
```

This is a query that reads ALL your articles ordered by id, so you don't have to write a query manually for every article.

```
    $a_result = pg_query($con, $a_query) or die("Cannot execute query: $a_query\n");

    while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($a1_result)) {
```

This while loop iterates over all articles. You will have every article in the variable `$row` inside the curly brackets.

```
        if($row['size']==1) { // If its a big value (Value 1) the news articles gets the div class blog-post
            echo '<div class="blog-post">
                    <h3>'.$row['title'].'</h3>
                    <p>'.$row['body'].'</p>
                </div>
            ';
        }
        elseif($row['size']==2) { // If its a small value (Value 2) the news articles gets the div class blog-post-smaller
            echo '<div class="blog-post-smaller">
                    <h3>'.$row['title'].'</h3>
                    <p>'.$row['body'].'</p>
                </div>
            ';
        }
    }
?>
```

I would advise you to try the code out and see if it works for you.

Comment: @krupp how would i print them in the Body?

Comment: The `echo` statements are already printing the blog posts. The code you got actually prints the posts like before just without the repetition.

Comment: Yes but .. If you look at my site. They cant just print after eachother .. sadly. I like this code, no doubt. But I want them to be printed by a specific statement, not as an array. Because I need them to be on different places.

Comment: Hmm.. i could do a longer if and include all code for that row.

Comment: Also one more thing. Can't I use the same While statement twice.

Comment: I got you. How do you determine where each article is displayed? How does the HTML markup differ for each article?

Answer (score 1):

Use IN to get articles.

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` where `id` IN (1,2,3,4)
```

In the array you will receive all the articles. Now prints it in the for loop

Comment: Can You Explain More please?